# Low Voltage Logic Inverter

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Currently, I am doing some experiments with Single Photon Avalanche Diodes where I get output voltage of 0.9V. And I am trying to invert the output using a regular inverter(74HC04). But, the Inverter considering 0.9V input is LOW, thus, giving me the HIGH output.

*Can I find any low voltage Inverter in the market that gives me LOW output when I give 0.9V as input?* Also, please suggest an alternative to solve my problem.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic however, if you gave more details in your question, you could get some ideas how to amplify the voltage and then use a comparator if that's what you want?

Answer (score 3):

The minimum supply voltage of HC family logic devices is specfied as 2 V.

If you use the search function of any logic manufacturer or distributor, you will find that logic families with supply voltages as low as 0.8 V exist (e.g., AUP, AUC).

Alternatively, use a comparator, where you can set the reference voltage directly.